# onError is called instead of onNext on 200 network response - RxJava, Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

As mentioned in the title onNext is not called when request responds with 200. It fires onError instead. LogCat doesn't show any errors. I am also sure that HTTP request responds with 200.

Here is my service interface

```
interface EnrollmentService {

@POST("enrollment/precheck")
fun sendPhoneNumber(@Body phoneInput: PhoneInputRequest) : Observable<Void>

}
```

Repository

```
class EnrollmentRepository(api : Retrofit) : BaseRepository(api) {
private val service = api.create(EnrollmentService::class.java)

fun sendPhoneNumber(phoneInputRequest: PhoneInputRequest) = service.sendPhoneNumber(phoneInputRequest)

}
```

And here is the method in the ViewModel that fires request:

```
 fun sendPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {
        if(!isNetworkAvailable(phoneInputResponse))
            return
        compositeDisposable.add(repository.sendPhoneNumber(PhoneInputRequest(PhoneNumber("+48", phoneNumber)))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { phoneInputResponse.postValue(Event(ApiResponse.success(null)))},
                {error -> phoneInputResponse.postValue(Event(ApiResponse.error(ResponseError.getErrorType(error)))) }
            ))
    }
```

Comment: So what is the error then?

Comment: @akarnokd Its a NullPointerException. The body of 200 response is empty. Could that be the problem?

Comment: your response type is void. You have to change Void to Object of your response.
`fun sendPhoneNumber(@Body phoneInput: PhoneInputRequest) : Observable<Any or Your Response Object Class>`

Comment: Did you try to use `Observable<Unit>` instead of `Observable<Void>`?

Comment: Observable<Void>  was the problem. API has changed, and once I added response object it worked. I have not tried that but I think Unit or Any would solve the problem in previous case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *just expecting* `response.code()` change the `return type` of the `sendPhoneNumber` method to `Observable<Response<Void>>` from `Observable<Void>`

So, use :-

```
fun sendPhoneNumber(@Body phoneInput: PhoneInputRequest) : Observable<Response<Void>>
```